# Joining pandas dataframes from array / list

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge (concat) dataframes selected from csv files.  I have previously achieve this manually but want to use a (tkinter) filedialog so that the user can select one or more files to use in the dataframe.  What I have is:

1. Read the filenames into an array until the user presses cancel - all good

```
while True:
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Open data file', filetypes=(("Comma separated values", "*.csv"),))
    if filename =="":
        break
    filenames.append(filename)
```

2. Use the filenames to generate a dataframe - all good individually (I think, as they print OK)

```
def read_Yokogawa(filename):
    frame = pd.read_csv(filename, header = 46, skiprows = [47, 48], low_memory = False, parse_dates = True, infer_datetime_format = True, na_values = ['+OVER', '-OVER'])
    print(frame)
    return frame

dfs=[]  #Set an empty array of dataframes
for filename in filenames:
    dfs.append([read_Yokogawa(filename)])   #Append each dataframe to the array
```

3. Concat the array of dataframes together - **not good**

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

I get the error: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ''; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

All the files have the same columns as they are generated by the same software.  I have also tried `pd.concat([dfs])` but get the same error.

Comment: It might help to include sample data and `type` of, for example, `dfs[0]` and `dfs[1]`, or `[i for i in dfs if not isinstance(i, pd.DataFrame)]`

Comment: Change `dfs.append([read_Yokogawa(filename)])` to `dfs.append(read_Yokogawa(filename))`.

Comment: I think your problem come from the square brackets. Try: dfs.append(read_Yokogawa(filename))

Answer (score 1):

Both @Quang and @Renaud suggested the same thing, which turned out to be a good answer to the question.

```
dfs=[]
for filename in filenames:
    dfs.append(read_Yokogawa(filename))
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```